# Prevent twitter bootstrap from changing existing element styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a complex site that has lots of CSS, including jQuery UI and more.

I have added twitter bootstrap 3 (latest at this time) and I wanted to use it just to style a single link as a button.

Well, I got the button and it is awesome!

But also, somehow my fieldset's `<legend>` element got a different styling, and my existing menu suddenly started using larger font-sizes, messing up my existing layout.

My impression is therefor that adding twitter bootstrap messes with your existing components, whether you like it or not.  I am not sure if it always does this, or if it is a complex interaction between my existing CSS and the bootstrap.

My question:  how do I limit bootstrap to styling my single button only (and leave the rest alone)?  Is that possible?

My code was:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 .....
<fieldset>

    <!-- somehow the legend text below changed from existing pre-bootstrap styling -->
    <legend>Menu Selection</legend> 
    <table>
 .....
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-info btn-lg">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
button</a>
```

Comment: It seems like overkill to include bootstrap for one link. Could you just copy the style the button gets from bootstrap (by inspecting it or something) then removing bootstrap completely?

Comment: well.. the idea is that I will eventually start using bootstrap more, but in a way you are right maybe I should not use bootstrap for a limited number of elements especially if this does not work as a drop-n-go technology for me

Comment: I haven't used bootstrap since the early versions but from what I understand it sets a lot of base css for you. That being the case, in my opinion using it for an existing site is going to be more trouble than it's worth. I doubt you'll find a way to isolate it's styles to part of your DOM (I hope someone gives you an answer though, I'd use it for sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you copy the Button style and include it in custom.css and ignore Bootstrap.css.

I don't think it's a good idea to include a big framework just to style a button/link?

Alternatively, use the Bootstrap customizer to download the parts you 'want' to use.

Also, you can create different versions of the Bootstrap.css file via division.

Here's an image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up removing twitter bootstrap and finding ways to use existing jQuery UI.

Comment: Can you explain how "stop-theme" is supposed to work? BTW, the current customizer (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) does not allow you to deactivate global styles.